# Select the last value of each column, with a single query

Tags: sql, null

Having the following data (blank means NULL):

```
ID    ColA    ColB    ColC
1     15              20
2     11      4       
3             3
```

How can I get the last not-NULL values of each column in a single query? So the resulting for the given data would be:

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
11      3       20
```

I have not found much, the function that seemed to do something similar to what I describe was `COALESCE`, but it does not work as expected in my case.

Comment: in LAST do you mean the MAX value?

Comment: @Blachshma no, though MAX would actually return the same data... just coincidence.

Comment: So how do you know what is last? Do you have some sort of primary key?

Comment: @Blachshma I have a timestamp, though I did not mention it in my example... Now I have edited to remove the coincidence I mentioned earlier, and added an INT key.

Comment: It's generally discouraged to to change the nature of the question **after** you already have answers - thereby voiding existing answers. Please ask a **new question** in such a case. You can always link back to this one for context. I rolled back to the original version

Comment: BTW, I have a nice solution for your follow-up question. Notify me if you should post it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes please post your solution, I just created [the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364126).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you would have to run a separate query per column with plain SQL. For a small table and only 3 columns, [@Guffa's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347626/939860) should be fine.

#### 3 window functions

You can do the same in one query with three window functions: Not sure if this is faster than three individual subqueries:

```
SELECT first_value(cola) OVER (ORDER BY cola IS NULL, id DESC) AS cola
      ,first_value(colb) OVER (ORDER BY colb IS NULL, id DESC) AS colb
      ,first_value(colc) OVER (ORDER BY colc IS NULL, id DESC) AS colc
FROM   tbl
LIMIT  1;
```

#### `count()` as window function

You can also exploit the fact that `count()` does not count `NULL` values.

```
WITH x AS (
   SELECT CASE WHEN count(cola) OVER w = 1 THEN cola ELSE NULL END AS cola
         ,CASE WHEN count(colb) OVER w = 1 THEN colb ELSE NULL END AS colb
         ,CASE WHEN count(colc) OVER w = 1 THEN colc ELSE NULL END AS colc
   FROM   tbl
   -- WHERE id > x -- safe to ignore a certain portion from a large table?
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER  BY id DESC)
   )
SELECT max(cola) AS cola, max(colb) AS colb, max(colc) AS colc
FROM   x
```

For bigger tables and more columns, a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) or a procedural function will be considerably **faster**:

#### Recursive CTE

```
WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
   SELECT cola, colb, colc
         ,row_number() OVER (ORDER  BY id DESC) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   )

   , y AS (
   SELECT rn, cola, colb, colc
   FROM   x
   WHERE  rn = 1

   UNION ALL
   SELECT x.rn
        , COALESCE(y.cola,x.cola)
        , COALESCE(y.colb,x.colb)
        , COALESCE(y.colc,x.colc)
   FROM   y
   JOIN   x ON  x.rn = y.rn + 1
   WHERE  y.cola IS NULL OR y.colb IS NULL OR y.colc IS NULL
   )
SELECT cola, colb, colc
FROM   y
ORDER  BY rn DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

#### PL/pgSQL function

My money is on this one for best performance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_last_nonull(OUT cola int
                                       , OUT colb int
                                       , OUT colc int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN

FOR r IN
   SELECT t.cola, t.colb, t.colc 
   FROM   tbl t
   ORDER  BY t.id DESC
LOOP
   IF cola IS NULL AND r.cola IS NOT NULL THEN cola := r.cola; END IF;
   IF colb IS NULL AND r.colb IS NOT NULL THEN colb := r.colb; END IF;
   IF colc IS NULL AND r.colc IS NOT NULL THEN colc := r.colc; END IF;

   EXIT WHEN NOT (cola IS NULL OR colb IS NULL OR colc IS NULL);
END LOOP;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_last_nonull();
```

```
cola | colb | colc
-----+------+------
 11  | 3    | 20
```

Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Would be nice if you could come back with a comparison of the solutions.

Comment: The recursive CTE option still seems to need to refer to each column separately. Am I right? Do you know any way to make the query accept any number of columns for this?

Comment: @user1598585: You would have to build dynamic SQL in a plpgsql function after looking up the columns in the system catalog. Feasible, but not as simple.

Comment: @user1598585: I added two more simple solutions.

Comment: I'd expect the solution with the windowing functions to be better than three individual queries - at least for tables where the sorting can be done in memory because the data only needs to be retrieved once.

Comment: @andrefsp: This one demonstrates an often overlooked feature: you can have a non-recursive CTE (additionally) even when declared `WITH RECURSIVE`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Probably true. For small to medium tables the effect might be nullified, because table itself would be cached for repeated reads?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Indeed. Its amazing what CTEs makes possible to achieve. I usually use WITH RECURSIVE to for instance get for leaf nodes on a tree table(id|parent_id) kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries:

```
select
  (select ColA from TheTable where ColA is not null order by ID desc limit 1) as ColA,
  (select ColB from TheTable where ColB is not null order by ID desc limit 1) as ColB,
  (select ColC from TheTable where ColC is not null order by ID desc limit 1) as Col
```